# c# Modify large File

Tags: c#

I have 1-2 GB size file. I need to find some string in the entire file and replace it with other string. Writing it into other file is not an issue. But i want to replace it in the same file. For small size file below code is working fine.

```
var InboxFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\AAAA\Desktop\Batch Docs");
foreach (var InboxFilePathNM in InboxFiles)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(InboxFilePathNM);
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    content = Regex.Replace(content, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", "?");
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(InboxFilePathNM.Remove(InboxFilePathNM.Length - 4, 4) + "_NEW.EXT");
    writer.Write(content);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Is there any anyway to replace the string with some other string in the same file. Can any one please guide.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do this in place. Is the replacement string the same length, or are you going to have to move content about? (Are you just turning non-ASCII into question marks?)

Comment: Process the file, line by line.

Comment: @leppie or even byte by byte, does it have lines?

Comment: IF the replacement data is the same length, you can overwrite. If not, it's easiest to process line by line writing the processed lines to a new file, then delete the old file and rename the new file to the old file.

Comment: Just change the Encoding of the `StreamWriter` to `Encoding.ASCII` and it should do what you want. Else inherit from that encoding and override the replacement character.

Answer (score 5):

This is not generally possible, certainly not with StreamReader/Writer.  Text files are *streams*, every line has an unpredictable length and can only be found by starting to read the stream from the start.  The core obstacle to *replacing* the line is that the replacement must be the exact same length as the original.  If it is not then the text beyond that line will be corrupted.  Either with a fragment of the original line surviving if the replacement is short or overwriting part of the next line if the replacement is long.

Maybe you have such a guarantee, you then need to use FileStream so you can properly find the position of the start of the line.  StreamReader is unsuitable, it reads ahead to deal with text encoding so the Stream.Position for its underlying stream is too large.  You must deal with bytes, first find the line-ending character ('\n'), then use the Encoding class to convert the bytes to text, then look for a match.  Seek() back to the start of the line to overwrite it.  The code is quite unpleasant if the file contains very long lines that don't fit in the byte[] you use, perhaps another shortcut you can take.

Just do keep in mind that writing this kind of code does not generally make the program any faster.  The slow part is *reading* the file, writing it is very fast.  Reading is slow because the file data needs to come off the disk and the program can't continue until that's done.  Usually around 30 megabytes/sec for a consumer grade spindle drive.  Roughly a minute for a 2 GB file.  Writing is very fast, a memory-to-memory copy into the file system cache.  From which it is lazily written to disk, usually long after the program ended.  Your code will only make it faster when the machine doesn't have enough RAM and the writes don't fit in the cache.

And beware of the test effect, it will *look* very fast while you are testing your program.  Because you run it repeatedly on the same file.  That makes reads fast, they come out of the file system cache.  That doesn't happen that often in real life.  Since it is reading that's the bottleneck, and you can't skip the reading requirement, you are not actually ahead with this kind of code.  Just make sure the machine has enough RAM, 8 gigabytes cost less than a hundred bucks.  A lot less than what you cost :)  And be sure never to need to wait for the program to finish.  Watching that grass grow makes any programmer go looking for a better way.  There of course is one, a database.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a good option could be using [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx). As FileOPtion you should use `SequentialScan`

> Indicates that the file is to be accessed sequentially from beginning
>   to end. The system can use this as a hint to optimize file caching. If
>   an application moves the file pointer for random access, optimum
>   caching may not occur; however, correct operation is still guaranteed.
>   Specifying this flag can increase performance for applications that
>   read large files using sequential access. Performance gains can be
>   even more noticeable for applications that read large files mostly
>   sequentially, but occasionally skip over small ranges of bytes.

You can also configure buffer size dimension, try some values and change the fastest that feets your needs (e.g. 1024).

After that you can parse the file line by line